# Spring Integration Tests for Resource Server (based on spring-cloud-starter-oauth2)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2, spring-test-mvc

I am using Spring Boot and Spring Cloud for a oAuth2 resource server. This is the configuration:

pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>

...
```

```xml
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
```

```xml
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
<version>Hoxton.SR8</version>
```

ResourceServerConfig

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${my-app.security.audience}")
    private String audience;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(audience);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll() // TODO: Enable basic auth for actuator
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceServerProperties resourceServerProperties() {
        return new ResourceServerProperties(null, null);
    }
}
```

OidcJwkTokenStoreConfig

```java
@Configuration
public class OidcJwkTokenStoreConfig {
    private final ResourceServerProperties resource;

    public OidcJwkTokenStoreConfig(ResourceServerProperties resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore jwkTokenStore(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        DefaultAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter = new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
        tokenConverter.setUserTokenConverter(new MvcUserAuthenticationConverter(userDetailsService));
        return new JwkTokenStore(this.resource.getJwk().getKeySetUri(), tokenConverter);
    }
}
```

Custom User Authentication Converter

```java
public class MvcUserAuthenticationConverter implements UserAuthenticationConverter {
    private final String SUB = "sub";
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public MvcUserAuthenticationConverter(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, ?> convertUserAuthentication(Authentication userAuthentication) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> map) {
        if (map.containsKey(SUB)) {
            Object principal = map.get(SUB);
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = getAuthorities(map);
            if (userDetailsService != null) {
                UserDetails user = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername((String) map.get(SUB));
                authorities = user.getAuthorities();
                principal = user;
            }
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, "N/A", authorities);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Map<String, ?> map) {
        if (!map.containsKey(AUTHORITIES)) {
            return null;
        }
        Object authorities = map.get(AUTHORITIES);
        if (authorities instanceof String) {
            return AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList((String) authorities);
        }
        if (authorities instanceof Collection) {
            return AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(StringUtils
                    .collectionToCommaDelimitedString((Collection<?>) authorities));
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Authorities must be either a String or a Collection");
    }
}
```

### How to do integration tests?

Unit Testing is not a big problem. But when it comes to Integration Tests, I'm struggling. How can I mock/skip providing a real bearer token? Prefered solution would be using `MockMvc` for Integration Tests.

I got the following so far:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
@ContextConfiguration(
        initializers = ProjectResourceTest.Initializer.class,
        classes = {ProjectResourceTest.ApiTestConfiguration.class, MyApplication.class}
)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ProjectResourceTest {
    @Container
    private static final MongoDBContainer mongoDB = new MongoDBContainer("mongo:4.2.5");

    public static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
            TestPropertyValues values = TestPropertyValues.of(
                    "spring.data.mongodb.uri=" + mongoDB.getReplicaSetUrl()
            );
            values.applyTo(configurableApplicationContext);
        }
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    public static class ApiTestConfiguration {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            MvcUser defaultUser = new MvcUser("default-user", "Default User");

            return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(singletonList(defaultUser));
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongo;

    @Test
    @WithUserDetails("default-user")
    void shouldReturnAllProjects() throws Exception {
        ProjectEntity project = ProjectFaker.newProjectEntity();
        mongo.save(project);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/projects"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.key", is(project.getKey())))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is(project.getName())))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.createdAt", is(project.getCreatedAt())));
    }
}
```

But this approach ends in the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create SecurityContext using @org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetails(setupBefore=TEST_METHOD, userDetailsServiceBeanName=, value=default-user)

    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.createTestSecurityContext(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.createTestSecurityContext(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:96)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:62)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeEach(SpringExtension.java:108)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$1(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:161)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$5(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:197)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:160)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.findUserDetailsService(WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.createSecurityContext(WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.java:58)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.createSecurityContext(WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.java:44)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.createTestSecurityContext(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:123)
    ... 61 more
```

My custom UserDetailsService

```java
@Service
public class MvcUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public MvcUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<UserEntity> user = userRepository.findByUserId(username);

        if (user.isPresent()) {
            return new MvcUser(user.get());
        } else {
            return createNewUser();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* do the following:

1. Override your resource server configuration for your test and make sure you put a valid RSA public key on your classpath (e.g. `/src/test/resources`):

Example `application.yml` inside `/src/test/resources`:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          public-key-location: classpath:id_rsa.pub
```

This should satisfy your application to start and does not require any HTTP communication with the authorization server.

2. Next, use the combination of `@SpringBootTest` and `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` to test against a mocked Servlet environment. Make sure you have the `spring-security-test` dependency available.
3. Get rid of your custom `UserDetailsService`bean inside your test and rather rely on the normal auto-configuration.
4. Now you can use e.g. `@WithMockUser` to provide a mocked user in the Spring SecurityContext while testing.

To provide a real bearer token during the integration test, you could do the following:

1. Override your configuration to point to a fake authorization server (e.g. use [WireMock](https://rieckpil.de/spring-boot-integration-tests-with-wiremock-and-junit-5/) to start a local HTTP server)
2. Mock the initial HTTP communication of your application (acting as a resource server) with the authorization serve where your application requests the JWKS. There you can create an in-memory RSA key pair and let the mocked identity provider return the public key
3. Create a valid JWT and sign it with the private key
4. Access your started application using e.g. the `WebTestClient` or `TestRestTemplate` and add the token as part of the request header (you need `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` for this)

Comment: mmh that doesn't work in my case. I am providing a custom instance of `JwkTokenStore` (see above) to use a custom `UserDetailsService` within my resource server. The configuration that you provided is for spring-boot-security. In my case I use spring-cloud-starter-oauth2 (and therefore another config is used). Seems like I messed something...?

Comment: could you add your custom `UserDetailsService`? Spring OAuth2 still uses a lot of infrastructure from Spring Security and hence you are also able to use e.g. `@WithMockUser` to _hard-code_ the authenticated user in the Security Context.

Comment: Add my custom UserDetailsService. The service impl always returns a User (from database). If the user is not present, a new one will be created.

Comment: @WithMockUser helped my to hard-code the authenticated user. This approach helped me to get my tests working. Thanks! :)